# How do I edit text color for shortcode?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, fonts, color-picker

I am trying to learn web development and using WordPress to make a site. I have Event Calendar, and Event Tickets Plugins. The Event Tickets Plugin uses short code to generate a checkout page after tickets have been selected. My site background is black and the text color on entire page is dark blueish/grey. How do I make the text color white so it can be seen on my background? All help appreciated and please use monkey terms because I am still learning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. I used the html source code to find the sections I needed to fix, and added custom CSS to alter the text color using the !important declaration to override any other CSS where needed.